# How to prevent Android Studio 2.0 from doing a complete clean build after uninstalling app from device?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, instant-run

I've been using Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5 with Gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta5. I've had Instant Run feature enabled, which is very useful when I want to do a quick change-and-test. Because it usually needs 50 seconds for my project to do a complete :assembleDebug. With Instant Run, I've been able to get my changed code running on device within about 10 seconds.

However, when I need to remove the app from the test device and have a complete new install. Android Studio always do the following thing when I click the "Run" button for the next time:

:clean, :generateDebugSources, :generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :mockableAndroidJar, :assembleDebug

This is very slow. It takes up about 2 minutes for my project.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour? Or why is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The instant run, in order to be faster only target the API of the selected device.

> Instant run uses different techniques to perform hot, warm, and cold swaps that
>   are specific to the API level of the target device

[Instant run ref.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

But if you just need to push the apk again, you can use the gradle task install... (in general install+Flavor+Type i.e.:installProdRelease installPaidDebug) or use ADB to install your APK manually.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.
Fixed by turning off  *Instant Run*
(File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run)